# How to map the country names in one enum to the time zone in another seperate enum

Tags: c, linux, enums, timezone, gmt

I am having an enum named Country like this,

**Enum_1:**
`typedef enum = {Pacific/Midway, America/Adak, Etc/GMT+10, Pacific/Marquesas, Pacific/Gambier}Country;`

and an enum for storing their corresponding time zones

**Enum_2:**
`typedef enum = {GMT-11:00, GMT-10:00, GMT-10:00, GMT-09:30, GMT-09:00}zone;`

I want to give the country as input from the user. When the input is given the code has to check the Country in Enum_1 and if the country is present, then it maps to the corresponding time zone in Enum_2

I know that enum returns only integer. I don't know whether we can map one enum to other

**Example input:**
`Pacific/Midway`

**Output should be:**
`GMT-11:00`

I am really confused about this. I want to know even if it is possible to implement this method in C?

Comment: I suggest using an array of `struct` which contains the necessary members for each territory. It looks as though those members need to be strings. If the user enters say "Mycountry" C cannot compare that with an enum identifier.

Comment: First of all those aren't valid identifiers in C so they make little sense. As for creating a relation between them, simply put each enum type in a struct and create an array of structs.

Comment: You've got a critical logical mistake with regard to time zones.  The first enum is not a list of countries, it's a list of time zones. Or more accurately, it's a list of IANA time zone identifiers.  The second enum is a list of *offsets* from GMT.  The mistake is assuming it's a one-to-one mapping. It is not.  For example, `America/Adak` is -10 during standard time and -9 during daylight time.  Please read more in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section "Time Zone != Offset".  (Someone else can answer about your C enum mapping question.)